# strange blue spots in statusline (vim-airline)

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-powerline, vim-airline

Some strange blue spots appear in my status line as I scroll or edit a buffer.
These spots are cleared after a `<C-L>`.
My `lazyredraw` option is `off`.
Here is a pic of the disturbance :
[image]

The status line is the **vim-airline** plugin and the font is **Anonymous** from **powerline-fonts**.
How could I set up an auto `<C-L>` of my status line after a move or an edit ?
The command :redraw does not clear my statusline ; only `<C-L>` does.
Thanks.

Comment: probably wouldn't hurt to upgrade your vid drivers either.

Comment: Thank you Marc, I have upgraded the vid drivers but the pb remains.

Comment: what system and terminal app are you using?

Comment: @ladislas, it appears on gvim 7.4 running on windows 8.1.

Comment: I'm not using windows so I can't say for sure, but sometimes on OS X the vim app (macvim or cli vim in iTerm) is doing similar stuff. I kinda got used to it :)